# Polymer installation

Tags: polymer

I'm a total noob at Polymer, I just installed it. However all I see is a blank page. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

What I did:
bower init, 
bower install --save Polymer/polymer#^1.2.0,
bower update,
python -m http.server,

I created these 2 files:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
</script>
<link rel="import" href="elements/hello­polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
<hello­polymer></hello­polymer>
</body>
</html>
```

elements/hello-polymer.html

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom­module id="hello­polymer">
    <template>
    <h1>Hello Polymer</h1>
    <p class=”ondertitel”>My first polymer element</p>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
    is: "hello­polymer"
    });
    </script>
</dom­module>
```

Comment: Try to run your project with the Polymer server instead
(polymer serve) or (polymer serve --open) 
And although you sad it is your editors fault please fix up your code as it might confuse others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello if you want to start with polymer then you should do this

> (open cmd in your folder) and run this
>
> polymer init
>   and select **polymer starter-kit**
>
> polymer serve --open

and then you should read this article on: [this site](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up).

Answer (score 1):

You said you ran "python -m http.server", the correct command is "python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port number(optional)]"

Also, on your index.html you've got:

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
```

Instead of

```
<script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
```

Comment: SimpleHTTPServer gives me an error, where http.server does boot up the server. The index is one folder higher so that path is correct.

Comment: There's not a space in 'dom module', could that be it?

Comment: I tried it, but it didnt work :/. I think I'll just do the start kit for polymer and then edit and see if it works. Very weird tho, since all the source-code looks good but the product just shows a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to name your element `hellopolymer`. Acc to WebComponents specification, the element's name must have **at least** on dash i.e.
`hello-polymer` instead of `hellopolymer`

An article here for more info: (https://www.webcomponents.org/community/articles/how-should-i-name-my-element)

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom­-module id="hello-­polymer">
    <template>
    <h1>Hello Polymer</h1>
    <p class=”ondertitel”>My first polymer element</p>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
    is: "hello­-polymer"
    });
    </script>
</dom­-module>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's because of the IDE I'm using (Atom). But the name is hello-polymer in all the cases that it's stated.

Comment: @SomeName Which browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome, which was recommended as one of the only browsers that works with Atom IDE in combination with Polymer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you spelled dom-module wrong and depending on the structure of your project you should add or remove the ../ on your imports as the answer above pointed out.
Instead of a SimpleHTTPServer you could just use polymer serve --open

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom­-module id="hello­polymer">
  <template>
   <h1>Hello Polymer</h1>
   <p class=”ondertitel”>My first polymer element</p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
     is: "hello­polymer"
    });
 </script>
```

If this is not working for you, the Polymer page gives a nice tutorial how to get started and set up the Polymer starter kit.
[Polymer Get set up](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up)

Comment: That's the IDE not showing the -'s. I'll try the start-up, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the command?

```
polymer serve --open
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 mistakes in your code:

1. A component name should contain a "-", so rename your component:`hello-polymer`.
2. In addition, there is a typo on in `elements/hello-polymer.html`: `dommodule` should be `dom-module`.

Answer (score 0):

For Polymer to run you have to install nodejs and npm, bower ,git and polymer cli.

Then you have to open cmd in your polymer starter kit and type polymer serve and host it

Then go to your browser and type localhost:8080 it will host all the pages which are written inside the source folder in polymer starter kit.